# Задача на деление шоколадки

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

Задача . Условие Шоколадка имеет вид прямоугольника, разделенного на n×m долек. Шоколадку можно один раз разломить по прямой на две части. Определите, можно ли таким образом отломить от шоколадки часть, состоящую ровно из k долек. Программа получает на вход три числа: n, m, k и должна вывести YES или NO. С некоторыми тестами работает с другими нет:

```
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    k = int(input())
    area = n * m
    last = area - k
    full_m = k / n
    if full_m == (area - last):
       print('YES')
    else:
       print('NO')
```

Comment: Ну давайте рассмотрим 5x1 шоколадку, нужны 3 дольки... У вас: area = 5, last = 2, full_m = k/n = 0.6 - что не равно 3, значит, по-вашему, нельзя... В то время как легким движением руки она переламывается в одном месте и мы получаем части из 3 и 2 долек :)

Comment: в данном алгоритме слом только вертикально расчитывается чтоли. 2й варианта слома не учитывается

Comment: Учитываются варианты слома и по вертикали и по горизонтали с принял за вертикаль m а горизонт - n. Есть просто способ что если last == m or last == n: print('YES')но этот вариант работает только тогда когда в ласт у нас осталась лишь одна полоска шоколада то-есть либо n либо m, а что делать если их там больше я хз уже туплю

Answer (score 6):

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
k = int(input())

if k < m*n and (k%m==0 or k%n==0):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Но интереснее вариант, когда ломать можно хотя бы пару раз :)

Answer (score 4):

Если  `к` делится на `м` или `н` без остатка, то YES.

Ну и разумеется, `к` должно быть меньше `м * н`.

Answer (score 2):

если шоколадка 4*3 и мы можем отламывать только строки или только столбцы, то нам и нужно посчитать сумму всех возможных столбцов (в нашем случае это 3, 6, 9, 12) и сумму строк (4, 8, 12). Если k совпадает с одним из этих чисел, то ответ "Да".

*(В большинстве учебных примеров не нужно стараться вывести целиком формулу ответа. Разбивайте большую задачу на мелкие до тех пор, пока они не становятся тривиальными.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
k=int(input())
if n*m<k or k==n*m:
    print ('NO')
elif k%m==0 or k%n==0:
    print ('YES')
else: 
    print ('NO')
```

Условие
`k==n*m` --> NO важно так как в случае если проверять только по кратности то шоколадку 3x1 можно будет разделить так чтобы в ней осталось 3 части

Либо так записать

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
k = int(input())   
if k <= m*n and (k%m==0 or k%n==0):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
k = int(input())
oppor_vert = "NO"
oppor_hor = "NO"
for x in range (n-1):
    left = (x+1)*m
    right = n*m - left
    if k == left or k == right:
        oppor_vert = ("YES")
for y in range (m-1):
    up = (y+1)*n
    down = n*m - up
    if k == up or k == down:
        oppor_hor = "YES"
if oppor_hor == "YES" or oppor_vert == "YES":
    print ("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Слишком заморочено и много лишнего. А деление в вашей школе не проходили?